# Can we remove the "helpful" dialog for Community ♦ flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, community-user

I noticed that there was a auto-flag from *Community ♦*. I noticed that it gave me an option to dismiss a flag as helpful or not.

Two scenarios that it wouldn't be ideal:

- Accidental click: we could just have a yes/no dialog pop up. This would still allow mods to back out before it's too late.
- Multiple flags: we could still dismiss them individually. A yes/now popup would appear and it would treat it as a normal flag.

This wouldn't be hard to implement: just a simple `if()` statement to tell if it's a community flag. If it is, just send another dialog. Otherwise, do the usual dialog. It's super simple and I'd think it'd be easier. Bonus: use the extra space to add a unicorn/waffles/ponies!

Photo:

[image]

Comment: I like to decline them when not useful, in the hope that the data is recorded somewhere (which I don't know: it isn't published anywhere that I know of — the flag summary of user -1 is the flags from deleted accounts) and that one day Community will be banned from flagging due to a >90% declined rate.

Comment: I've always marked them helpful out of fear of flag-banning Community, which would probably severely bork the site. :-P